# How can I fix font shadow and font stroke not appearing properly on my WordPress website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm building a website on WordPress and upon trying to change the font shadow and font stroke, the changes do not appear properly on the webpage.

For my title, I wrote this CSS:

```
.wp-block-heading-h1 {
    text-decoration: underline  dotted purple;
    text-shadow: black -4px 5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    color: white;
}
```

```css
.wp-block-heading-h1 {
    text-decoration: underline  dotted purple;
    text-shadow: black -4px 5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wp-block-heading-h1">S. CRAP</h1>
```

The output is this:

[image]

Whereas, upon highlighting I get this which should be the expected output:

[image]

Comment: I created a snippet and it does come out with white text. So that I'm guessing you have CSS that is overwriting your color CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below CSS to achieve the expected result:

```css
.wp-block-heading-h1 {
    text-decoration: underline dotted #fff;
    text-shadow: black -3px 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: coral;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wp-block-heading-h1">S. CRAP</h1>
```

Your output would look like this:

[image]